# Unable to Auto Scroll in TableView Programmatically to a Specific Portion

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working ios in Objective C.
I have a tableView in xib.
In that tableView, there are customTableViewLabel 
And under label, there are some customTabelViewTextCells.

I want to perfrom auto scroll programmatically for a specific height when next custom cell is clicked.
I attached screen short

[image: My table View Image is attached]

I have Custom Label which is in the case Dog, Human.
I want that, when user clicks on 8, from Dog 1 to 7 will automatically be scrolled. And on the screen top, will shows the Human 8.

That's I want.
Please help me. I need help.
In Advance, Thanks

Comment: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                             animated:YES];

Comment: Thanks. It's works Fine